# linq, selecting columns as IEnumerable<DataRow>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ado.net

how can i do in linq:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> query = 
        from rec in dt.AsEnumerable() 
        where rec.Field<decimal>("column2") == 1 && foo(rec.Field<decimal>("column1"))
        select new {
            column1 = rec.Field<decimal>("column1"),
            column2 = rec.Field<decimal>("column2"),
            column3 = rec.Field<decimal>("column3")}  ;
```

this does not work. Im trying to select some columns as new datatable then join it later with some other datatable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LinqEntityDataReader
and then select your values like this:

```
DataTable query = 
        (from rec in dt.AsEnumerable() 
        where rec.Field<decimal>("column2") == 1 && foo(rec.Field<decimal>("column1"))
        select new {
            column1 = rec.Field<decimal>("column1"),
            column2 = rec.Field<decimal>("column2"),
            column3 = rec.Field<decimal>("column3")}).ToDataTable();
```

A much more simple solution, that doesn't require external libraries, would be to create a DataTable (if you don't already have one), and populate it as follows:

```
// declaring a data table.. Replace it with whatever code you want
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("column1", typeof(Decimal));
table.Columns.Add("column2", typeof(Decimal));
table.Columns.Add("column3", typeof(Decimal));

// Populate the table
(from rec in dt.AsEnumerable() 
where rec.Field<decimal>("column2") == 1 && foo(rec.Field<decimal>("column1"))
select new {
    column1 = rec.Field<decimal>("column1"),
    column2 = rec.Field<decimal>("column2"),
    column3 = rec.Field<decimal>("column3")})
    .Aggregate(table, (dt, r) => { dt.Rows.Add(r.column1, r.column2, r.column3); return dt; });

// at this point your table variable is populated
```

Comment: Fair enough.. Added an alternative solution.. Much better, cleaner. Seems like what you'd want, no? :)

Comment: (1/2) Hi @ArtiomChilaru  
I've a slight different scenario. Want a new datatable in o/p  
 with row values from two datatables. I've used join.  
  
**dtMain:**  
`ID | Company  
1 | XYZ  
2 | PQR`  
  
**dtDetails:**  
`ID | ParentID (FK)         | Amount  
1 | 1    | 11  
2 | 1    | 12  
3 | 2    | 44`  
  
**Required o/p:**  
  
`ID | Company | Amount  
1 | XYZ  | 11  
1 | XYZ  | 12  
2 | PQR  | 44`  
  
continue..

Comment: (2/2)  
**LINQ query I've written: **  
`var query = (from M in dtMain.AsEnumerable()  
join D in dtDetails.AsEnumerable()  
on Convert.ToString(M["ID"]) equals Convert.ToString(D["ParentID"])  
select new  
{  
Convert.ToString(M["ID"]),  
Convert.ToString(M["Company"]),  
Convert.ToString(D["Amount"])  
});`  
  
I'm able to get the `List<string[]>`.  
Can you tell me how to get `DataTable`? (I've tried to get `DataRow[]` but it didn't work).